# media queries not working on heroku-deployed site, css not loading in landscape mode

Tags: django, css, heroku, responsive-design, media-queries

I want my site, when viewed on my phone, to show one color in portrait mode and another in landscape mode.  The problem is that:

1. When I start in portrait mode, it works.  even after refreshing.  But when I rotate my phone to landscape mode, it works once.  Refreshing or rotating back to portrait results in the loss of styling, ie. the css file isn't loaded.
2. When I start in landscape mode, no styling.  When I rotate to portrait, I start in the exact situation as in scenario 1.

FYI, I'm using django and deploying on Heroku. It seems to work ok - I didn't encounter any styling issues on my desktop.  (I removed the media query for desktop screens in the code below.)
When I said "start" earlier I meant toggling this command: `heroku ps:scale web=1`

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=yes" />

    </head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 384px)" 
        href="{% static 'home/style.css' %}" />

    <div id="wrapper"><div class="hello"><p>hello.</p></div></div>
</html>
```

and

```
/* nexus 4 landscape mode */
@media only screen and (min-width: 385px) {
    .hello {
        color:  firebrick;
        font-size: 5em;
    }
}
/* nexus 4 portrait mode */
@media only screen and (max-width: 384px) {
    .hello {
        color: greenyellow;
        font-size: 4em;
    }
}
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    padding-top: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: cornsilk;
}
```

Comment: I tried: 1) a larger min-width then 385px, 2) Adding a 3rd Media query that covers both landscape and portrait mode.  (what's that good for by the way?)

Comment: I tried 3) accessing it from the local network instead of the internet.  ie. using gunicorn bound to 192.168 instead of deploying to heroku.